# Access-Control-Allow-Origin when trying to get social shares count

Tags: jquery, twitter, google-plus, linkedin-api, social-networking

I try to get count of social networks count, in my case it's twitter, linkedin and gplus. I made a call with jquery to social networks api but got an error in my browser console for all three social networks (accessing the same urls from browser works ok)

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://maki.host.com:3000/blog/posts/fdsfdsfds. Origin http://maki.host.com:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

(for twitter)

I try to modify my headers to allow my host by nothing changes, maybe someone have the same problem and can help me. Thanks

Comment: Going to go out on a limb and guess it's the port. I could be wrong though.

Comment: I tried on port 80 too but result is the same

Comment: Guess my hunch was wrong then :c

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using the APIs for each respective Social Media site as opposed to using AJAX to directly try and scrape or make API calls. As an example, the following will retrieve an Activity on the Google+ network that you can use to retrieve engagement counts:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.get?activityId=z120dncann32i3gu222uydqhrp34gx5np&fields=object(plusoners%252Creplies%252Cresharers)&_h=3&

For Google+ you should be using the official Google+ API client, demonstrated on the [Google+ JavaScript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/javascript).

As another example, if you are trying to get a count of people who have mentioned a user on Twitter, [explore the API for Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/console) to find the query you are looking for.

You would then use one of the various [JavaScript libraries for Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries) to manage API calls.

For Facebook, you should be using the [Facebook JavaScript library](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).